# Find the measure of the segment $PI$ in the figure below

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

> In triangle $ABC$, where $\angle A=2\angle C$, the internal angle bisector $AM$ is drawn such that $BM = 4$ and $MC = 5$. Let $I$ be the incenter of $\triangle ABC$. The angle bisector $BI$ intersects $AC$ in $P$. Calculate $PI$.
>
> [image: nama of image]

My progress:

$\triangle ABC \sim \triangle MBA\implies \frac{AB}{4}=\frac{9}{AB}\therefore AB = 6\\
\frac{AC}{5}=\frac{AB}{4} \implies AC =\frac{15}{2}\\
\triangle ABC:\frac{AP}{PC} = \frac{AB}{BC}=\frac{6}{9}=\frac{2}{3}\\
AP+PC = \frac{15}{2} \implies \frac{2PC}{3}+PC = \frac{15}{2}\therefore PC = \frac{9}{2}, AP =3\\
 \triangle ABP: \frac{AP}{AB}=\frac{PI}{BI}=\frac{3}{6}\implies BI=2PI\\
BP = \frac{2}{b+c}\sqrt{bcp(p-a)} = \frac{2}{9+6}\sqrt{9.6.\frac{45}{4}.(\frac{45}{4}-\frac{15}{2})}=\frac{9\sqrt2}{2}    
\\ \therefore PI =\frac{3\sqrt2}{2}\approx 2,12
$

[image]

Comment: Did you use the fact that $\triangle MBA \sim \triangle ABC$?

Comment: Answer $\sqrt{3}$ is wrong

Comment: @MathLover   I completed the calculations and found $AB, AC , AI$ and $IM$.., now I would use the theorem of the internal angle bisector $AC$ and then by similarity find the internal bisector of $ AMB$?

Comment: $AI$ and $IM$ are not needed. Once you find $AB$ and $AC$, $AP:PC = AB:BC$ and you can find $AP$ and $PC$. $AP:AB$ gives $PI:BI$. Now you can find length of angle bisector $BP$ and then find $PI$ knowing the ratio $PI:BI$.

Comment: @MathLover  I believe it worked now... if there is no calculation error :)

Comment: GeoGebra gives $IP\approx 2.12$

Comment: @Intelligentipauca  there is an error in the account..i will correct it

Comment: $p = 37/4$ is wrong. Rest is fine. You should get $\frac{3}{\sqrt2}$

Comment: @MathLover I've seen this error and I'm correcting it

Comment: Please use text, and **not** an image to present the main part of the problem. Please use text, explicit propositions, to show the own progress. Above there are a lot of `\implies` and `\therefore` pictograms, i.e. $\implies$ and $\therefore$ signs, that make reading the question a problem of compiling letters and characters. Instead, explaining the progress in words, and joining the arguments together would make the presentation readable and understandable. And $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle MBA$ is "a problem", since in the picture $\angle BAI\ne \angle IAC$. Please draw a better picture.

Comment: @dan_fulea  Particularly I don't see any problems in using mathematical signs since we are in a mathematics forum and I believe it is clear for everyone who uses it. Mathematical language is universal and so it allows anyone in the world to understand it different from a text placement that will allow only users of that language understand the solution.

Comment: @dan_fulea  △ABC∼△MBA is "a problem"?? See that it is an initial drawing and it was mentioned that it was not to scale..when we are solving a question for a test or a book we don't have computational tools..so the drawing is just a freehand reference...see that the second drawing is just to show the reality.. but I will try to make more coherent drawings and as for the mathematical symbols if it is mandatory that we use text I will do it but it is the first one in more than 4 years that someone mentions something like this. Greetings

Comment: The $\Delta ABC$ has in the given pictures an angle $\widehat{MAC}$ visibly smaller than $\widehat{MAB}$, also $I$ is visibly closer to $AC$ than to the other sides. The "no scale" insertion in the picture make no sense for me. However it is the most readable content from the picture. Using freehand may be better. For the usage of text please note that this is a site where **questions** are posted. Above there is no question. It is hard to present a question as you do it above. So which is the question? It is not "Calculate $PI$", which is an imperative. We already had this discussion.

Comment: @dan_fulea The term "without scale" is precisely to indicate that the figure is just a reference but where the nomenclature of the points and angles and measures provided are placed but that do not represent in a real way precisely for those who are deciding not to stick to the dimensions of the figure and yes in algebraic development..In Peruvian books the vast majority of images are completely out of scale and that does not cause difficulties in resolution... but as I said I will try to make better images

Comment: @dan_fulea In the titles I no longer use the term calculate although on the site there are more than 400,000 titles using this term...In the reference statement I reproduce the exact copy of the book's statement because many users question whether there are no errors in the statement so the term calculate appears